# Propogation delay in sequential logic

Tags: verilog

Im building a pipelined processor, and it seems that the sequential logic is creating a 1-cycle delay in my PC getting updated from the value in PCFetch. My verilog code as follows

```
always@(posedge clk)
begin
   if(rst)
     PC <= 0;
   else
    PC <= PCFetch;
end
```

PCFetch is an output from another module instantiated. So assume clock cycle X, PCfetch is updated to 0002. However the update to PC happens only at only clock cycle x+1. I heard that is a propagation delay due to sequential logic. Is there any way to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always going to have propagation delay in sequential logic.  Sequential logic means logic that propagates between two flip flops.  The fastest the signal will propagate is 1 clock cycle between the two flip flops.

If you DONT want to use sequential logic, you can use combinatorial (combinational) logic.  For your example above it would look like this:

```
assign PC = PCFetch;
```

This would not be in an always block.

Comment: I used assign PC = rst ? 16'b0 : PCFetch;

That should have the same logic as my sequential block right/

Comment: @kype You should really be resetting your PCFetch signal, since that is the one that I assume is your flip-flop.  You do not need to reset a combinatorial signal.